# How can i display the ggplots generated in java by rJava in html?

Tags: java, html, r, jboss

I have created a java code to run r script using rJava to create ggplots graphs.how can I show this plot in HTML or embed in HTML?

With this code

```
 `Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);`
 `engine.eval("hist(rnorm(1000,40,123))");`
```

I can open a console window in eclipse. but I'm having trouble to send this result to HTML. 
i tried to create JPEG file with the result but I want something interactive with mousehover and such functions.

Comment: Save to a graphics file format that you know how to display in a directory that you know how to find. You are not likely to get the "interactive" features.

Comment: I am looking for interactive. not any static images. any idea about it

Comment: You should look at the code for one or more of the GUI's. You should be trying to emulate that code's use of stdin and stdout.